# A question about Big-O notation

Tags: calculus, analysis, asymptotics

I know that if $f(n)=O(g(n))$ then $\log(f(n))=O(\log(g(n))$ under the conditions $f(n)\geq 1$ and $\log(g(n))\geq 2$ for all sufficiently large $n$.
Is this true also for the exponential? I mean, is it true that if $$f(n)=O(g(n))\Longrightarrow e^{f(n)}=O(e^{g(n)})$$
as $n\to\infty$?

Thanks.

Comment: Your original claim is false. Take e.g. $f=g=n$. Maybe you meant $\log f(n)\in O(\log g(n))$.

Comment: Look at $f(n) = 2n$, $g(n) = n$.

Comment: @J.G. Yes, you're right. I already corrected it.

Comment: @martini Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It is straightforward to show that it cannot be correct. As in $O$ notation, any multiplication can be transferred to a non-constant function in exponentiation. A simple counterexample is mentioned by @martini in the comment. When $f(n) = 2n$ and $g(n) = n$, then $f(n) \in O(g(n))$. But, $e^{2n} \not \in O(e^n)$. Hence, $e^{f(n)} \not \in O(e^{g(n)})$.